# Yii2 Kartik Pagination BUG

Tags: pagination, yii2, kartik-v

Need an advice.

It appears that ANY setting of filters on one report -- even something as simple as records per page -- disrupts how other reports appear in a rather buggy looking way.

For example:
    Go into my page > some view

```
Set Page Size to 13 and click Apply.
```

Now it's showing 13 records per page. BUT this simple setting has now trashed nearly every other pages view, which now only displays those fields that were in the view personalised. Other records are hidden.

What can I do in this case?